# DocumentApp SaveAndClose() throw Service unavailable: Docs

Tags: google-apps-script

This code create a document, copy it in a folder, the add text and images, no footer.
When I CloseAndSave the document, often (not always) I have: "Service unavailable: Docs".

```
//create a Google Doc
var rootDoc = DocumentApp.create(docName); 
var idDoc = rootDoc.getId();
var origDoc = DriveApp.getFileById(idDoc);
//move to folder
var newFile =  origDoc.makeCopy(docName, folder);
DriveApp.removeFile(origDoc);
//open
var newDoc = DocumentApp.openById(newFile.getId());
var body = newDoc.getBody();
body.setMarginTop(40);
body.setMarginBottom(40);

//IMG HEADER DOC
var logo = UrlFetchApp.fetch(PROP.getProperty("URL_LOGO_OVS")).getBlob();
body.appendImage(logo).setHeight(40).setWidth(87);

body.appendParagraph('My File').setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.HEADING1).setAlignment(DocumentApp.HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);
body.appendHorizontalRule();

//IMAGE
var tab2 = body.appendTable([
    ['','']
  ]).setBorderWidth(0).setAttributes(textStyle);

 tab2.getCell(0,0).appendParagraph('FOCAL').setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.HEADING2);
  tab2.getCell(0,0).appendParagraph('Rispetto del criterio espositivo: '+theForm.valBrFoc);
  if (theForm.noteFocal != null && theForm.noteFocal != '') { tab2.getCell(0,0).appendParagraph('Note: '+theForm.noteFocal); }

  var inline2 = tab2.getCell(0,1).appendImage(img2).setLinkUrl("https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id="+img2.getId());
  if (tab2.getCell(0, 1).getChild(1) != null) {
tab2.getCell(0, 1).getChild(1).asParagraph().setAlignment(DocumentApp.HorizontalAlignment.RIGHT); 
  }
  inline2.setWidth(150).setHeight(100);

//TEXT
body.appendParagraph('VETRINA: non presente.').setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.HEADING2); 

//this throw error: Service unavailable: Docs (blank document)
newDoc.saveAndClose();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem! In my form (HTML client), there was a textarea .. so .. when the user click return the string had \n\r inside! But the addParagraph say that \n is not supported!!
I resolved with a replace for the text from textArea:

```
str.replace(new RegExp('\r?\n','g'), '\r');
```